# Getting error using Date format as input in another function

Tags: python, datetime

This is my script with 2 functions...

```
from jugaad_data.nse import derivatives_df
from datetime import timedelta, date
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def oi_data(Symbols):
  baseurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
  url = f'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities'
  headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, ''like Gecko) ''Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36','accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
  session = requests.Session()
  request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=30)
  cookies = dict(request.cookies)
  params=[('symbol', Symbols)]
  res = session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, timeout=30)
  res_text = res.text
  data = json.loads(res_text)
  exp_dt1 = data["records"]["expiryDates"][0]
  datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(exp_dt1, '%d-%b-%Y')
  exp_dt = datetime_obj.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
  print(exp_dt)
  return exp_dt
  
def fut_data(Symbols):
    ticker_df = derivatives_df(symbol=Symbols, from_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = 30), to_date= date.today(),expiry_date=date(2023,11,30), instrument_type="FUTSTK")
    fut_df = ticker_df
    print(fut_df)
    return fut_df

Symbols = ['MARUTI']
for symbol in Symbols:
    exp_dt = oi_data(symbol)
    fut_df = fut_data(symbol)
```

Here, from oi_data function I'm getting exp_dt in specific format which is required in case of my second function fut_data.

Now I want to use this exp_dt in my fut_data function. More clearly I'm trying to write my 2nd function as....

```
def fut_data(Symbols):
    ticker_df = derivatives_df(symbol=Symbols, from_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = 30), to_date= date.today(),expiry_date=exp_dt, instrument_type="FUTSTK")
    fut_df = ticker_df
    print(fut_df)
    return fut_df
```

But here I'm getting error as ...

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

What is the solution here plz ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems your expiry_date (I mean the return "exp_dt") is a string and must be inputted as datetime variable. Your issue should be solved removing:

```
exp_dt = datetime_obj.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
```

and writing instead:

```
exp_dt = datetime_obj.date()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to help me. Thanks a lot. My query is solved now.